# Search for my most upvoted comments

Tags: support

Is there a way that I can search through which comments I've got the most upvotes from? I think it would be interesting.

It would also be nice to see other users high rated comments.

Does this kind of functionality exist? Could we add this?

Again, it's small, but would be a nice-to-have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70480/my-most-upvoted-comments) at the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

The data is not real-time, however.

Here's [another query](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/60098/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text) that includes comment text.

Comment: Just a note for other who may not notice that second one is for electronics stack exchange (which is why it returned 0 results for me). In the URL change 'electronics' to 'stackoverflow' (or another exchange) as desired e.g. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60098/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text