# How can you view the most upvoted comments on your posts (answers and questions)?

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer

Is there a way to view the most upvoted comments from any of my answers or questions on Stack Overflow?

There are two *similar* questions/answers:

- [Search for my most upvoted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237711/389220) and
- [Can I view a list of my "great comments", perhaps in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/can-i-view-a-list-of-my-great-comments-perhaps-in-my-profile)

They give a user's most upvoted comments, but not the most upvoted comments on a user's questions/answers, which is different.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I'll explain the use case because it might make it a lot clearer what I wanted to do. Sometimes I see a question or answer with a highly upvoted comment asking for some sort of sensible adjustment. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928390/what-does-has-unmet-peer-dependency-mean-when-installing-a-package-with-yarn#comment114982226_48767033) is an extremely good example. I wanted to know if any of my questions/answers had any such requests, and this query would tell me (at least in a rough way). *Cont.*

Comment: That's all I wanted to do. I didn't necessarily care if it was someone else's or my own comment which was upvoted, just that it was on one of my posts. Hope that clarifies what problem the query helps solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter your user id in this query on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer:

[Most upvoted comments on your questions and answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1712152)